# Type 'IResolvers<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLResolverMap<any>'. Index signatures are incompatible

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I follow the guide for [Apollo Federation: Implementing services](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/implementing-services/)

Code here:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql, IResolvers } from 'apollo-server';
import { buildFederatedSchema } from '@apollo/federation';
import faker from 'faker';

const MemoryDB = {
  users: [
    { id: 1, name: faker.name.findName() },
    { id: 2, name: faker.name.findName() },
  ],
};

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    userById(id: ID!): User
  }
  type User @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
  }
`;

const resolvers: IResolvers = {
  Query: {
    me: (_, { id }, { db }) => {
      return db.users.find((u) => u.id === +id);
    },
  },
  User: {
    __resolveReference(user, { db }) {
      return db.users.find((u) => u.id === user.id);
    },
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: buildFederatedSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }]), // TSC throw error here
});
```

TSC throw an type error:

> Type 'IResolvers<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLResolverMap'.
> Index signatures are incompatible.
> Type '(() => any) | GraphQLScalarType | IEnumResolver | IResolverObject<any, any, any> | IResolverOptions<any, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarType | { [enumValue: string]: string | number; } | { [fieldName: string]: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, any, { [argName: string]: any; }> | { requires?: string | undefined; resolve: GraphQLFieldResolver<...>; }; }'.
> Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarType | { [enumValue: string]: string | number; } | { [fieldName: string]: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, any, { [argName: string]: any; }> | { requires?: string | undefined; resolve: GraphQLFieldResolver<...>; }; }'.
> Type '() => any' is not assignable to type '{ [fieldName: string]: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, any, { [argName: string]: any; }> | { requires?: string | undefined; resolve: GraphQLFieldResolver<any, any, { [argName: string]: any; }>; }; }'.
> Index signature is missing in type '() => any'.ts(2322)

Package versions:

```
"apollo-server": "^2.12.0",
"@apollo/federation": "^0.17.0",
```

It seems that `IResolvers` interface is incompatible, but `GraphQLResolverMap` interface is not exposed so I can't import and use. I don't want to cast the type of resolvers to `any` type. Is this a bug?

**UPDATE**

The issue still there after updating `apollo-server` to `"apollo-server": "^2.15.1",`

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this one out? I'm wrestling with the same thing `apollo-server: 2.24.0` and `@apollo/federation: 0.25.0`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that GraphQLResolverMap is elsewhere, try:

```
import { GraphQLResolverMap } from 'apollo-graphql';
```

and then use it instead of IResolvers.